# React: imported async functions resolving automatically despite awaiting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been stuck with this for a week, in my react native app I import an object with async functions related to geolocation, when I call one of the methods the function resolves and returns undefined automatically despite awaiting it, and being fired from an async function!

```
import  geolocationApi  from '@utils/geolocationApi';

const handleUpdateLocation = async () =>
    {
        try
        {
const root = useMobxStore();            
const result = await geolocationApi.requestLocationPermissions(root,true);
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            throw error;
        }
    };
```

My geolocationApi file

```
import { AsyncStorage ,Platform, Alert, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash';
import env from '@env/vars';
import http from '@env/axiosin';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';



    
const geolocationApi = {
        
    

    async requestLocationPermissions(root, getCityName = false)
    {
        try
        {
            let granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) 
            {
                root.mapStore.setLocationEnabled(true);
                
                let results = await this.getGeolocationCoords(root, getCityName);
                //returns { currentCoordinates, newCity }
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                root.mapStore.setLocationEnabled(false);
                return false;
            }

    } 
    catch (error)
    {
        throw error;
    }
    },


    async getGeolocationCoords(root,getCityName)
    {
        if (this.hasLocationPermission) 
        {
            return Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                async (position) => 
                {
                    let coords = position.coords;
                    let newCity = false;
                    let currentCoordinates = { lat:coords.latitude, lng:coords.longitude };

                    root.mapStore.setCurrentCoordinates(currentCoordinates);
                    if(root.userStore.user)
                    {
                        root.userStore.setLat(currentCoordinates.lat);
                        root.userStore.setLng(currentCoordinates.lng);
                    }
                           
                    if(root.mapStore.city == '' || getCityName)
                    {
                        let params =
                        {
                            latlng : currentCoordinates.lat+','+currentCoordinates.lng,
                            sensor : true,
                            key : env.MAPS_KEY
                        };
                        let response = await http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?', { params :params });
                        newCity = response.data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
                        root.mapStore.setCity(newCity);
                    }
                            
                    return { currentCoordinates, newCity };
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log(error.code, error.message);
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    },


    async  hasLocationPermission()
    {
        
    
        return true;
      }

 
    };
    
    export default geolocationApi;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you catch error to throw it in the next line?

Comment: I don't understand, I should not throw it?

Comment: Why would you throw an error that you just caught? Do you deploy a parachute just to throw it away a second later and crash into the ground? Don't catch it at all if you don't want to do anything with it or handle it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing several return statements:

```
if (this.hasLocationPermission) { // There is no else, so if this is false it will be undefined on the return
```

```
 // In this block there is no return value so if it hits this side of the if, you will get undefined
            else
            {
                root.mapStore.setLocationEnabled(false);
            }
```

Also, the `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` does not return a promise. Unfortunately in the base web api, this is quite common. It returns undefined as described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#return_value). That means, the value is only available in the callback unless you go your way to make it available outside. If you want it to return a promise with the resolved value you need to wrap it in one, and use `resolve` instead of return inside the callback function:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                async (position) => 
                {
                    let coords = position.coords;
                    let newCity = false;
                    let currentCoordinates = { lat:coords.latitude, lng:coords.longitude };

                    root.mapStore.setCurrentCoordinates(currentCoordinates);
                    if(root.userStore.user)
                    {
                        root.userStore.setLat(currentCoordinates.lat);
                        root.userStore.setLng(currentCoordinates.lng);
                    }
                           
                    if(root.mapStore.city == '' || getCityName)
                    {
                        let params =
                        {
                            latlng : currentCoordinates.lat+','+currentCoordinates.lng,
                            sensor : true,
                            key : env.MAPS_KEY
                        };
                        let response = await http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?', { params :params });
                        newCity = response.data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
                        root.mapStore.setCity(newCity);
                    }
                            
                    resolve({ currentCoordinates, newCity });
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log(error.code, error.message);
                  reject(error)
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
            );
}
```

Comment: I added your changes but I'm still getting same error, I also updated OP with said changes

Comment: Ah I see the issue. Edited answer